# Why Electron requires extra quotes for content-disposition filename?

Tags: electron, content-disposition

I try to download a file from ASP.NET Core to Electron app.
I see that ASP.NET Core properly quotes filename in content-disposition header but Electron cuts it to the first comma.

If I add extra double quotes in ASP.NET Core it works correctly (but adds additional undescores for normal browsers). Is it an issue with Electron or am i missing something?

To be more specific:
From ASP.NET Core Content-Disposition header send is

```
attachment; filename="[User, Test]"; filename*=UTF-8''%5BUser%2C%20Test%5D
```

In Electron filename received is

```
[User
```

Now if i artificially add quotes:

```
attachment; filename=""[User, Test]""; filename*=UTF-8''%5BUser%2C%20Test%5D
```

It will be ok in Electron

Comment: Please add more details.

Comment: I added an issue on the Electron on this but they closed it. So yes I can also confirm that.

Comment: It looks loke a bug in Electron to me. Is that ticket public?

Comment: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/29346